# XAML Change Frame Background Based on Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I have an ObservableCollection which is based on the following class:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

This observablecollection is used and binded as ItemSource for ListView. The following is DataTemplate for displaying data -

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
        <Frame OutlineColor="White" HasShadow="False">
             <!-- Data -->
        </Frame>
    </ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
```

Since the ObservableCollection is a collection of Data class which has a **boolean property**, I want to **use it in order to change the frame's background color**:

- If property IsActive is true - BackgroundColor is Red
- If property IsActive is false - BackgroundColor is Blue

I've looked into implementation of Triggers, however I can't seem to get them working correctly, and I'm not sure what I'm missing.

According to Xamarin Documentation I should be able to do :

```
<Frame>
    <Frame.Trigger>
        <!-- -->
    </Frame.Trigger>  
</Frame>
```

However that doesn't seem to be possible. Neither is this -

```
<Frame>
<Frame.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Frame">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Blue" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Frame.Style>
</Frame>
```

The code above gives the following error message:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 28:26. The Property TargetType is required to create a Xamarin.Forms.DataTrigger object.
```

Comment: Are you sure the line numbers match where your frame style is defined?  I'm not sure about xamarin, but possibly try using the {x:Type } extension instead of relying on string -> type conversion in the TargetType property?

Comment: Are you setting your `BackgroundColor` from directly in the `<Frame>` tag? If so, that property will override any triggered or styled values. Another thing to try is maybe use `TargetType={x:Type Frame}`, occasionally I see the text string fail to resolve into the actual type, so this prevents that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure about your trigger problem but I think you should be able to accomplish the color changing by first implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on your Data class like so:

```
public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    private bool _isActive;
    public bool IsActive 
    {
        get { return _isActive; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _isActive)
            {
                return;
            }

            _isActive = value;

            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsActive");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your xaml, you should be able to do something like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
        <Frame Background="{Binding IsActive, Converter={StaticResource IsActiveToColorConverter}}" OutlineColor="White" HasShadow="False">
             <!-- Data -->
        </Frame>
    </ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
```

Where IsActiveToColorConverter looks something like:

```
public class IsActiveToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var isActive = (bool) value;

        return isActive ? "Red" : "Blue";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: OP Did not mention that boolean property will be changed real time. so NotifyProperty is not required. But Converter is a good option for this scenario. So +1 for that.